# Problems With Validation on Ajax - PHP

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I have a issue, I have a form login designed in PHP validated in Ajax, the form login work's well, but I need to add a validation for the user type (Administrator, User) and I have modified my code like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'log.inout.ajax.php',
    data: 'login_username=' + $('#login_username').val() + '&login_userpass=' + $('#login_userpass').val(),

    success:function(msj){
        if ( msj == 1 ){
            $('#alertBoxes').html('<div class="box-success"></div>');
            $('.box-success').hide(0).html('Validacion Completa, Bienvenido al Sistema');
            $('.box-success').slideDown(timeSlide);
            setTimeout(function($tipo){
            if ($tipo=='ADMIN'){
                window.location.href = "../Main2/Index.php";
                }else{
                window.location.href = "../Main1/Index.php";
                }
            },(timeSlide + 500));
        }
        else{
            $('#alertBoxes').html('<div class="box-error"></div>');
            $('.box-error').hide(0).html('Datos Incorrectos, No Tiene Acceso al Sistema ');
            $('.box-error').slideDown(timeSlide);
        }
        $('#timer').fadeOut(300);
    },
    error:function(){
        $('#timer').fadeOut(300);
        $('#alertBoxes').html('<div class="box-error"></div>');
        $('.box-error').hide(0).html('Ha ocurrido un error durante la ejecución');
        $('.box-error').slideDown(timeSlide);
    }
});
```

The problem is that the variable "$type" is not validating for AJAX, so I need your help to solve this issue

This is the validating file to the form:

```
<?php
session_start();
$user = $_POST['login_username'];
$pwd = $_POST['login_userpass'];

if ( !isset($_SESSION['username']) && !isset($_SESSION['userid']) ){
    if ( $idcnx = mssql_connect('(local)','sa','.') ){
        if ( mssql_select_db('DB_Demo',$idcnx) ){

            $sql = "SELECT [USER],PASSWD,NOMBRE,APELLIDOP,TIPO FROM T_LOGIN WHERE [USER] ='$user' AND PASSWD ='$pwd'";

            if ( $res = mssql_query($sql) ){
                if ( mssql_num_rows($res) == 1 ){

                    $user = mssql_fetch_array($res);
                    $_SESSION['userid'] = $user[0];
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $user[1];
                    $_SESSION['unombre'] = $user[2];
                    $_SESSION['uapellido'] = $user[3];
                    $_SESSION['utipo'] = $user[4];
                    $tipo = $_SESSION['utipo'];

                    $_SESSION['autentificado']= 'SI'; 
                    $_SESSION['ultimoAcceso']= date('Y-n-j H:i:s'); 

                    echo 1;
                }else{
                    echo 0;
                    }
            }
            else{
                echo 0;
                }
        }
        mssql_close($idcnx);
    }
    else{
        echo 0;
        }
}
else{
    echo 0;
}
?>
```

thanks...

Comment: Which variable $type..?

Comment: You can't use a php variable directly in your ajax/javascript - `setTimeout(function($tipo){if ($tipo=='ADMIN'){`. Ajax has no idea what `$tipo` is.

Comment: the variable $type = $_SESSION['utipo'] declared for my SQL Query....and my issue is how can I validated this variable on my ajax function

Comment: Also, your validating code only sent username and password; those will be the only data validated

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to send a php variable back to ajax.. correct?

the standard way to do this would be to json encode whichever items youre trying to get back from php, and then echo it out.  I notice that you are echoing out numbers and using those in jquery.  you need to send $tipo the same way.  You can put those together in an array and then echo them out using json_encode.  example.

```
echo json_encode(array('number' => 1,'type' => $tipo));
```

then you will use msj variable in javascript.  it will contain both of your variables

```
var bothVariables = jQuery.parseJSON(msj);
console.log(msj.number)  // will give you 1
console.log(msj.tipo)   // will give you Admin
```

another simple example

here is ajax.php

```
echo json_encode(array('number' => 1,'type' => 'Admin'));
```

here is jquery getting variables from that

```
        $.ajax({url:"ajax.php",success:function(result){
                result = $.parseJSON(result);
                console.log(result.number);  // 1
                console.log(result.type); // Admin
          }});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to solve this issue like @hamobi says, but Ajax not yet validating the variable $tipo.....I think better posting the Ajax original file

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var timeSlide = 1000;
    $('#login_username').focus();
    $('#timer').hide(0);
    $('#timer').css('display','none');
    $('#login_userbttn').click(function(){
        $('#timer').fadeIn(300);
        $('.box-info, .box-success, .box-alert, .box-error').slideUp(timeSlide);
        setTimeout(function(){
            if ( $('#login_username').val() != "" && $('#login_userpass').val() != "" ){

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'log.inout.ajax.php',
                    data: 'login_username=' + $('#login_username').val() + '&login_userpass=' + $('#login_userpass').val(),

                    success:function(msj){
                        if ( msj == 1 ){
                            $('#alertBoxes').html('<div class="box-success"></div>');
                            $('.box-success').hide(0).html('Validacion Completa, Bienvenido al Sistema');
                            $('.box-success').slideDown(timeSlide);
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                window.location.href = "../Main2/Index.php";
                            },(timeSlide + 500));
                        }
                        else{
                            $('#alertBoxes').html('<div class="box-error"></div>');
                            $('.box-error').hide(0).html('Datos Incorrectos, No Tiene Acceso al Sistema '/* + msj*/);//msj significa el error que presenta el login
                            $('.box-error').slideDown(timeSlide);
                        }
                        $('#timer').fadeOut(300);
                    },
                    error:function(){
                        $('#timer').fadeOut(300);
                        $('#alertBoxes').html('<div class="box-error"></div>');
                        $('.box-error').hide(0).html('Ha ocurrido un error durante la ejecución');
                        $('.box-error').slideDown(timeSlide);
                    }
                });

            }
            else{
                $('#alertBoxes').html('<div class="box-error"></div>');
                $('.box-error').hide(0).html('Los campos estan vacios');
                $('.box-error').slideDown(timeSlide);
                $('#timer').fadeOut(300);
            }
        },timeSlide);

        return false;

    });

    $('#sessionKiller').click(function(){
        $('#timer').fadeIn(300);
        $('#alertBoxes').html('<div class="box-success"></div>');
        $('.box-success').hide(0).html('Terminando Sesion....Espere....&#133;');
        $('.box-success').slideDown(timeSlide);
        setTimeout(function(){
            window.location.href = "logout.php";
        },2500);
    });

});
```